# Apache Nifi GetFTP Processor Dynamic input

Tags: apache-nifi

Is it possible to pass dynamic properties like ftp host, port etc to GetFTP processor. I tried it but somehow GetFTP processor is not accepting any upstream connections.
Basically I want to keep the ftp configuration for all the sources in one file and use just one GetFTP processor to read that information. Isn't it the correct way?

Answer (score 6):

The Get* processors are source processors which do not accept input connections. For most applications there are complementary List* and Fetch* processors. The List* gets a list of objects that exist somewhere. Then a typical flow would pass that information to the Fetch* processor to grab the necessary files.

Correct me if I'm wrong but, what you want is a FetchFTP processor to pass FlowFiles to and evaluate the Hostname, port, filename, etc. using expression language.

While there are ListSFTP and FetchSFTP, currently there is no FetchFTP. There is a ticket open to create them[1] and a user recently emailed the mailing list offering them as a contribution[2] but I am waiting to hear back.

[1] https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NIFI-1844

[2] http://apache-nifi.1125220.n5.nabble.com/Contribution-ListFTP-and-FetchSTP-processors-td8133.html

Update: The ListFTP and FetchFTP processors have been committed to master and will be in the next 1.X release

https://github.com/apache/nifi/commit/be83c0c5b2b8a435b4745cbfc43f7c9251561727

Comment: You are correct I am looking to pass ftp parameters using expression language. Thanks for sharing the Jira tickets.